# Button Styling OuterGlowBitmapEffect -> DropShadowEffect

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0

In .NET 3.5 I used OuterGlowBitmapEffect on MouseOver event and it worked perfect.

Now I'm moving to .NET 4.0 and there does not working - is deprecated, so I rewrote my code to DropShadowEffect.

It works, but there is long delay between mouse over and animation start - about 500ms. Does anyone know why please? Or what am I doing wrong?

Style:

```
<Style x:Key="Button" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<Style.Setters>
    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="Yellow" BlurRadius="800" RenderingBias="Performance" Opacity="0" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style.Setters>
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect.Opacity" From="0" To="1" By="1" BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect.Opacity" From="1" To="0" By="1" BeginTime="0:0:1" Duration="0:0:0" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

And button:

```
<Button Content="B1" Canvas.Left="207" Canvas.Top="321" Height="70" Name="btn1" Style="{StaticResource Button}" Width="380" />
```

Comment: do you use 'AllowsTransparency = True' in your window by any chance?

Comment: Yes, but this does not effect...

Comment: You mean that you tried setting it to false but it didn't speed things up? it is a known issue.

Comment: Yes, I tried both options, maybe on the first on mouse over is slower when is AllowsTransparenci = False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the BlurRadius property in the animation, instead of the Opacity. Also you can use AutoReverse property, to go back to initial state:

```
    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="Yellow" 
BlurRadius="0" RenderingBias="Performance"/>
```

And the animation:

```
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect.BlurRadius" 
From="0" To="100" Duration="0:0:0.2" AutoReverse="True"/>
```

And you should get a similar effect that starts without any delay.

Comment: Thank you, this is much better, on one button perfect, when multiple buttons too slow... The problem was elsewhere, value of Effect.BlurRadius must not exceed 100!

Comment: There you go, glad I could help.